# Evaluate a variable every time it is used in a code

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to use a global variable integer array that is initialized to be empty at first and a function fills it in at a later point in time.

However, the main function takes the initial null value of the array even after the function returns some integers.

Is there some sort of type qualifier in python that can avoid this compiler optimization?

Example:

```
intArr = []
intArr = foo()
print intArr

def foo:
    return <some integer array>

print intArr
```

Output:

```
NULL
```

Comment: Hi , please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how best you should put forward this question

Comment: When you assign a function's return value to a variable it doesn't get called every time you use that variable. You should call the function again, or refactor it into a class and make it a property if you want to omit parentheses.